# Can we get a midpoint, or right-most number, for bins and labels using pd.cut?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm testing this code.

```
labels = pd.interval_range(start=0, freq=1, end=55)
bins = pd.interval_range(start=0, freq=1, end=55)
dataset['DVScores'] = pd.cut(dataset['DV'], bins=bins, labels=labels).fillna(labels[0])
```

It is giving me ranges of score, but not integers.  So, I'm seeing this:

```
        DVScores  
0         (10, 11]  
1           (2, 3]  
2           (1, 2]  
3           (0, 1]  
4         (13, 14]
```

I'd love to get it into a format like this:

```
11
3
2
1
14
```

I looked at mid and right, but I couldn't get it to give me just one number.  I believe, if you hard-code it, like this:

```
bins = [0, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, np.inf]
```

I have a lot of these things, and they are all slightly different, so I'd love to be able to do it more like this:

```
bins= pd.interval_range(start=0, freq=1, end=55)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of `dataset['DV']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the right value of the bin. Which you can retrieve with:

```
dataset['DVScores'].apply(lambda x: x.right)
```